# password is not working in Zip file through PHP

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, zip, locking

I am creating the function which helps to I could lock the zip before extract or view it.
with the help of all zip password related threads on StackOverflow I could not achieve this output.

from my end, I think it right. but what are the mistake I could not understand and why the code not works.
below what I am trying - please help me jow to fix this.

```
$dir = './';
$zip_file = 'file.zip';

// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath($dir);

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->setPassword('MY_PASSWORD');
// Create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
 //Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
 if (!$file->isDir()) {
 // Get real and relative path for current file
  $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
  $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

 // Add current file to archive
  $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
 }
}

$zip->setEncryptionName($zip_file, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256); //encrypt it
// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zip_file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_file));
readfile($zip_file);
```

Comment: $zip->setEncryptionName($zip_file, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, 'myPassword');

Comment: it is not , working

Comment: Do you have php version 7.2 or higher in order to run this code?

Comment: I am using PHP latest version

Comment: a test i did worked on my ubuntu server

but i had to `sudo apt install php-zip` and `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` 

and use `7z x -ptest123 test.zip` to unzip it, where `test123` was my password.